# java: stop child process

Tags: java, windows, process

Is there any way to start non-Java process from Java and then stop it? Or at least send some keyinput to it (e.g. alt+f4)?

E.g. I start java app, then javaapp start notepad, then javaapp send alt+f4 to notepad. Javaapp will run from Administrator account.

Question is only about Windows OS.

Comment: Any way to get Process object that was started before java app started ?
E.g. i start notepad, then i start java app, and java app get Process object for running notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: missed question about starting...

To create, use [Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String))

To destroy, use: [Process.destroy()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy())
From the javadoc:

> Kills the subprocess. The subprocess represented by this Process object is forcibly terminated.

Comment: No problem. I couldn't find an answer to your comment/addendum.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new process with [`Runtime.exec()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29). Then get the standard input of the returned process with [`Process.getOutputStream()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and push input to it. In the end you can [`destroy()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy()) it.

Note that you must consume all output from the process to make it run correctly.